# react native sliding navigation bar

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I'm with react native on android, and i have the navigator component with it's navigation bar.
In my main view i have a tabbed android-like component, and list views to display my articles.

So my question is : what would be the best scheme to create a hide-on-slide navigation bar ? something that follow the scroll of the list view, so that the tabs and the navigation bar slide up, hiding the navigation part (a classic effect on content apps, like medium).

I have been researching two ways without success : getting the scroll from my list views and somehow applying a transform animated style to my navigation bar and my tabs... But I am struggling making the navigation bar an animated component

Another way would be to translate the whole navigator with this scroll number, but the result is not great, flickering a lot, because of the displacement of the scrolling component and recalculation of the scroll parameter from the new position.

And a last proposition : embedding my navigator inside a scroll view so that when you scroll navigation bar goes out of screen... But then i loose the scroll on the list views inside the navigator's tabbed views.

Any thoughts ?

Comment: Try using https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-nav-bar as navigation bar might work nice on native